# Looking to publish first App what do i need to know

Tags: android, google-play

OK i have a web page that i converted to an App. Its a data driven picture rating site. I used a webview to load the page in the app. I have tested it on my phone and tablet it works like it should.

What more should i be testing or planning for. It will be a free app.

Is there a check list of things that will get you denighed from the market?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to prefer video so I would recommend [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GxU8N21wfrM) and [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CttbUBzBKBg)

The first one is from Google I/O 2011 and the second one is from Google Developer Day.

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty good article here explaining the steps to take before submitting an App to the market -
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html